# Android 4.4 - Immersive mode top bar

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-4.4-kitkat

Does immersive mode work differently in android 4 or am I doing something wrong? When hiding the top bar in android 4 I am getting a dark bar instead of my app scaling to the screen

android 10

[image: android 10]

android 4.4
[image: android 4.4]

Ive tried two methods of hiding the bar but they both have the same result. The first was using flutters

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

The second way I tried was by setting immersive mode via kotline as described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#kotlin

Both result in that dark bar. If there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work differently. If you're using [immersive mode on Android 4.4](https://youtu.be/_mGDMVRO3iE?t=604) (Kit-Kat) the system draws a translucent bar for you. The translucent property with the shade of pink you use for the toolbar gives a darker color for the status bar.

Comment: Okay thankyou, is there no way to hide it completely?

Comment: You have no way of accessing the status bar in immersive mode. Unless you want to remove immersive mode specifically for Android 4.4 devices. @NO_ob